# How would I access an int variable from one class to another? (Java)

Tags: java, bukkit

For example:

**In Class One**

```
int killcount = 0;
```

**In Class Two**

```
killcount = 5;
```

---

All I want to do I get the variable from one class to another class. How would I do that?

Comment: google about instances, settters and getters....

Comment: You can do that by learning the basics of Java. Or by searching on the Internet or here. This has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: This is an extremely basic thing that you ask and is usually solved by creating public getter methods. Please note that the down-votes are for your lack of demonstrated research effort on this subject before asking, and that this site is not supposed to be used as a substitute for your studying the basic rudiments of a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to work with Bukkit I'd recommend you to get some Java experience first. That's not meant as an insult, but it can get quite confusing if you do it the other way round. Anyways, if you still want to know the answer to your question:

You'll have to create a getter & setter for your "killcount" variable.

```
class Xyz {

    private int killcount;

    public void setKillcount(int killcount) {
        this.killcount = killcount;
    }

    public int getKillcount() {
        return this.killcount;
    }

}
```

Of course this is a simplified version without checks, but if you want to access the variable from a different class you can create an instance and use the methods to modify it.

```
public void someMethod() {

    Xyz instance = new Xyz();
    instance.setKillcount(instance.getKillcount() + 1);
    //this would increase the current killcount by one.

}
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to use the same instance of the class if you want to keep your values, as creating a new one will reset them to default. Therefore, you might want to define it as a private variable too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the examples

```
public class Test {
    public int x = 0;
}
```

This variable x can be accessed in another class like

```
public class Test2 {
    public void method() {
        int y = new Test().x;
        // Test.x (if the variable is declared static)
    }
}
```

Ideally, the instance variables are made private and getter methods are exposed to access them

```
public class Test {
    private int x = "test";
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int y) {
        x = y;
    }

}
```